# Why stripe webhook is returning 400 error and how to fix it?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to get the webhook working for stripe but constantly getting the following error: `Webhook Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing`. I have followed their documentation and read through other SO users who had the same issue but still no success. Here is what I have in my code:

**index.js**

```
app.use('/webhooks/stripe', bodyParser.raw({type: "application/json"}), stripeWebhookRouter);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  verify: function(req,res,buf) {
    var url = req.originalUrl;
    if (url.startsWith('/stripe-webhooks')) {
        req.rawBody = buf.toString()
    }
  }
}));
```

And here is my stripe webhook file that listen on certain endpoint

**stripeWebhook.js**

```
let stripeSecretKey;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    stripeSecretKey = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET_PRODUCTION;
}else{
    stripeSecretKey = process.env.STRIPE_SK_TEST;
}

const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeSecretKey);

const stripeWebhookRouter = Router();

stripeWebhookRouter.post('/stripeWebhook', async (request, response) => {
    console.log("Stripe webhook working")
    const payload = request.body;
    const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
    let event;

    try {
        event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, stripeSecretKey);
        console.log("Stripe event constructed ", event);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`❌ Error message: ${err.message}`);
        return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }
    // I have more code logic here, but it is irrelevant to this question
}
```

Am I setting up the bodyParser wrong for the Stripe router?

Answer (score 0):

Okay fellow developers, I think I nailed the solution and if anyone faces similar issue please take look at my solution. I also strongly suggest that you have separate file for your router collection, because this will ensure that your index.js file is not clogged with bunch of routers.

So the issue appeared to be not being able to pass down raw incoming request to the stripe webhook endpoint. Here is my code change:

**index.js**

```
app.use('/webhooks/stripe', express.raw({type: "*/*"}), stripeWebhookRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if(req.originalUrl.startsWith('/stripe-webhooks')){
    next();
  }else{
    express.json()(req, res, next);
  }
})
```

and here us my **stripeWebhook.js**

```
    const payload = request.body;
    const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
    let event;

    try {
        event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, stripeWebhookSecretKey);
        console.log("✅ Stripe event constructed ", event);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`❌ Stripe event construction failed, error message: ${err.message}`);
        return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }
```

Pay attention to how you parse incoming requests to your stripe webhook endpoint. Cheers!